# Display issue while add control Programmatically  in WP7 using Visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I have Created Mobile Application Using Visual Studio 2010  C#. There i have created one button Programmatically  and Add that button into  Contentpanel .While running my app i got Button display successfully.
But it has Following issue 
-that Button Always Display Center of the Content panel even i have metion the thickness as(0,0,80,80)

-I have tried to add that button into Layoutroot   , Button Display better in Y postion  But X position  center of the Layoutroot

Here i have enclosed my code for ur reference

```
    Button nw = new Button();                        
   nw.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 80, 150);      
   ContentPanel.Children.Add(nw);
```

Comment: What is the layout of the ContentPanel? When you add control to a container, the position of the control depends on the layout of the container

Comment: Grid is the layout of ContentPanel,in page load button dynamically create and have to position the left,top of the screen

Comment: Then you probably need to use absolute layout as only in that layout you can set a child control top and left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this?

```
       Button nw = new Button();    
       nw.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
       nw.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;                    
       nw.Margin = new Thickness(80, 150, 0, 0);      
       ContentPanel.Children.Add(nw);
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what else is also in `ContentPanel` - which I assume is the grid from the default template.

If there is nothing else in it then it will take up the whole space occupied by the grid, minus the space you have allocated to the margin.

Please provide a complete example which demonstrates the behaviour you are seeing and tell us what you are trying to achieve. (How do you want the button to be displayed?)